# How to configure Service Fabric to support only HTTPS connections but not http?

Tags: azure, https, azure-service-fabric

I have Azure service fabric cluster created on local test environment & deployed microservice based web apis, it working well without any issues. But would like to enable HTTPS traffic on cluster level and want to stop HTTP requests

**https**://mytestsf.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8800/  => expecting this one to work

**http**://mytestsf.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8800/  => expecting this one **NOT** to work

Is Support only for HTTPS traffic can be done on Azure service fabric level? if yes, how?

P.S: This service fabric cluster not having any external network component like traffic manager or application gateway in front of it as it is local test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation - [add an HTTPS endpoint using Kestrel - Azure Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint#define-an-https-endpoint-in-the-service-manifest).